# Resharper Keep Freezing on open particular project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash, resharper, freeze

i used Visual Studio 2013 permeium, and resharper 13 ,
when ever i open an specific project, resharper freezing ,

i have to suspend resharper inorder to open that project ,

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Resharper 13, wow, that must be a pre-pre-pre-alpha version, I suppose you can expect some issues with it. Resharper is on Version 9 currently, is this what you meant? Also give more detail on 'freezing', it may be smething to do with your code being made up of some white squiggles :)

Comment: thanks , it's resolved , I didn't touch the visual studio for half  n  hour, i think Resharper need to do some sort of work to get my project running

Answer (score 0):

Resolved
I opened my project and did not touch it and after half an hour without freezing the project was Opened